# "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" Error in Kivy Launcher

Tags: android, python, ssl, python-requests, kivy

I'm building a short python script, logging into a website and grabbing some data on the page, using requests.
The script runs perfectly fine on my Mac, but when launched in Kivy Launcher, I get a certificate error, and the data is not grabbed
The code is as follows :

```
s = requests.session()
response = s.post('URL', data=form)
responsetext = response.text
```

On my Mac, responsetext is the data I need. On Android, I get the same message as here : ["SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error) and the variable remains empty.   I of course have tried the solutions proposed in the said post, but they are of course NOT working.
I can't use Kivy's UrlRequest because I need to stay logged into the website (and thus using Requests' sessions)

Thanks !